# Javascript prototype inheritance doesn't call expected method

Tags: javascript

Why does this print out 'bye' instead of 'hello'? According to the inheritance chain as is described in this blog post, I would've thought it would log 'hello'.

http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/02/22/a-plain-english-guide-to-javascript-prototypes/

```
class Test {
  hello() {
    console.log('hello')
  }
}

Test.prototype.hello = function(){
  console.log('bye')
}

const t = new Test
t.hello()
```

Comment: Why do you overwrite `Test.prototype.hello` if you don't want that? What else did you expect to happen with the bye-function?

Comment: Do you know how `class` syntax works? What do you think does the inheritance chain of `t` look like according to the article you read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are rewriting the definition of hello on the "prototype".
When you do class Test () ... hello is the equivalent of

Test.prototype.hello

The class syntax is mostly sugar on top of the normal prototypical definition of a function.